# How to remove JSON field from payload factory using WSO2 EI Enrich Mediator?

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have a payload with many fields but i would like to send only the fields that they are not empty to the Backend ,so i tried to use enrich mediator to remove those fields if they are empty but i got an error .

This is my payload factory :

```html
                        <payloadFactory media-type="json">
                            <format>
                                {
  "_putupdateuser": {
                 "BADLOGINS": $1,
                 "EMAIL": "$2",
                 "FRAMED_ROUTE": "$3"
                       }
}
</format>
                            <args>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('BADLOGINS')"/>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('EMAIL')"/>
                                <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('FRAMED_ROUTE')"/>
                            </args>
                        </payloadFactory>
```

This is my implementation of enrich mediator :

```html
                        <enrich>
                            <source clone="false" xpath="json-eval($._putupdateuser.FRAMED_ROUTE)"/>
                            <target action="remove" type="body"/>
                        </enrich>
```

This is the error i got :

```
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Unexpected value at line 3 column 32 path $._putupdateuser.BADLOGINS
at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.syntaxError(JsonReader.java:1568)
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Enrich+Mediator), this feature is only available as a WSO2 update. Hence try a solution like using the Script Mediator as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68254818/2627018).

Another option is to not add the element at all if the values are null. You can have an `Enrich mediator` within a `Filter Mediator` and if only the value is not empty you can add the element. Refer the sample 2 [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI660/Enrich+Mediator).